# How to convert this MySQL query to a equivalent Laravel 5.4 Elequent/query builder query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

```
SELECT `id` FROM `jobs` WHERE `job_type` IN ( 'topemployercheckbox1','topemployercheckbox2') OR `job_category` IN ( 'Contract','Intern') ;
```

---

I need to Convert this MySQL query to a  laravel 5.4  query builder query.

Comment: Before you ask a question your are expected to try out it yourself. You should have done your research and you should be able to submit your findings here and state what worked and what not. Then only members of SO be able to suggest alterations and improvement. You cannot expect members of SO to write code for you. Learn [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to Laravel5. I searched a lot, there are orWhere and whereIn but I did not find anything like orWhereIn. I don't agree with you that  " You cannot expect members of SO to write code for you. Learn  ".  I didn't ask for an exact code, even small guidance would have helped me.

Comment: Since you say you've searched a lot that's means you may have come up with some sort of code. It's not working that's why you are asking for help. You could've published it. Then the people who try to answer really know you've tried and need improvement. Instead You start the question by asking "how..?" and shows the expected output and asks "I need to convert.." Its seems like you are asking for help without tiring.

Comment: As for not finding `orWhereIn`, just do a simple google search for `orWhereIn` and the first result you get is [Is there a orWhereIn in Query Builder](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/is-there-a-orwherein-in-query-builder)

Comment: Don't assume everything by yourself. I searched and whatever result you are saying comes first, I even saw that and it doesn't talk anything about **orWhereIn** . So do work if you have instead of unnecessary poking. Oh bdw it's **trying** not tiring ( you should have searched for correct spelling before writing, it seems you want members of SO to correct your spelling ).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the spelling mistake. It's very kind of you. I only wish you've put as much effort in preparation of your question.

Comment: I only wish you've put as much effort in preparation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
ModelName::whereIn('job_type',['topemployercheckbox1','topemployercheckbox2'])
    ->orwhere(function($q){
          $q->whereIn('job_category',['Contract','Intern'])
})->get('id');
```

or

```
ModelName::whereIn('job_type',['topemployercheckbox1','topemployercheckbox2'])
    ->whereIn('job_category',['Contract','Intern'],'or')->get('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union of two whereIn query.

```
$query1= \DB::table("jobs")select("id")->whereIn("job_type",['topemployercheckbox1','topemployercheckbox2']);
$query2=\DB::table("jobs")select("id")->whereIn("job_category",['Contract','Intern']);
$job_ids= $query1->union($query2)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be like as below. Here we have considered your model name is as Job.

```
 Job::select('id')
    ->whereIn('job_type',['topemployercheckbox1','topemployercheckbox2'])
    ->orWhereIn('job_category',['Contract','Intern'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alankar, I searched but I didn't get  **orWhereIn**. Thanks, for help.

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L931 You can see this method which is internally calling whereIn by providing third parameter as 'or'